# Extract Variables, Coeffcients & Powers from a Polynomial string (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, math, polynomials

I am trying to extract different parts of a polynomial string like variables, coefficients and powers from a string in javascript. So far I am able to extract these from a simple polynomial string e.g. "-13x^2+2-12x^4".

I want to extend this to extract from a relatively complex polynomial string. Something like "-13x^2y^3+2-12x^-4".

Here is the code that I have:

```
function extractPolynomial(polynomialStr) {
    var arr = [];
    polynomialStr = polynomialStr.match(/[+-]?\d+(x|y)(\^\d)*|[+-\s]\d+/g);
    polynomialStr.forEach(function (match) {
        var vals = match.split('^');
        var coeff = parseInt(vals[0]);
        var variable = vals[0].match(/[a-z]/gi) ? vals[0].match(/[a-z]/gi)[0] : "";
        var power = 1;
        if(vals.length > 1){
            power = parseInt(vals[1]);
        }
        else {
            if (variable === "") {
                power = 0;
            }
            else {
                power = 1;
            }
        }
        arr.push({
            coeff: coeff,
            variable: variable,
            power: power
        })
    });
    return arr;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/889ruq7a/

Comment: This is definetly far more conplex than a simple regex.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of research on regex I got what I wanted.
Here is the function to extract all the information from a polynomial:

```
function  extractPolynomial(polynomialStr) {        
    var arr = [];
    polynomialStr = polynomialStr.match(/[+-]?\d*(x|y)(\^\d)*((y|x)(\^\d)*)*|[+-\s]\d+/g);
    polynomialStr.forEach(function (match) {
        var variable = match.match(/([a-z]\^\d|[a-z])/gi) ? match.match(/([a-z]\^\d|[a-z])/gi).join("") : " ";
        var coeff = parseFloat(match.split(variable)[0]);
        var power = 1;
        var variables = [];
        if (variable != " ") {
            var tempVars = variable.match(/([a-z]\^\d|[a-z])/gi);
            for (var i = 0; i < tempVars.length; i++) {
                var oneVariable = { variable: "", power: 0 };
                oneVariable.variable = tempVars[i].match(/[a-z]/gi)[0];
                var tempV = tempVars[i].split("^");
                if (tempV.length > 1) {
                    oneVariable.power = parseFloat(tempV[1]);
                }
                else {
                    oneVariable.power = 1;
                }
                variables.push(oneVariable);
            }
        }
        else {
            variables.push({ variable: "", power: 0 });
        }
        arr.push({
            coeff: coeff,
            variables: variables
        });
    });
    return arr;
};
```

Here is the fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/khubaib/40hm80qu/5/